# How to draw a scatter plot where we get information for each points?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Data :

```
Taluka_name     Y         X
AKOLA         2509.5    103.03
AKOT          2007.8    91.23
BALAPUR       1384.3    109.47
BARSHI        1364.9    92.58
MURTIJAPUR    1209      100.37
PATUR         363.2     103.68
TELHARA      846.9      83.38
```

I want to draw a scatter plot , where my points will be show me this point for this taluka_name.

I want to display  "Taluka_name"with corresponding scatter points.

I tried following code, but I got only scatter points in a graph ,not corresponding "Taluka_name" with points.

Code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> data = pd.read_csv('/home/desktop/Desktop/Akola.csv')
>>> df=data.set_index('Taluka_name')
>>> df.plot(kind='scatter', x='X', y='Y')
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fc051099390>
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: "I can't get Taluka_name for corresponding point" is not understandable. Clearly state what the resulting plot looks like and in how far this does not meet your expectation. Do so by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> data = pd.read_csv('/home/desktop/Desktop/Akola_kharif.csv')
>>> ax = data.plot.scatter(x='X', y='Y', alpha=0.5)
>>> for i, txt in enumerate(data.Taluka_name):
    ax.annotate(txt, (data.X.iat[i],data.Y.iat[i]))


<matplotlib.text.Annotation object at 0x7f668f2fc310>
<matplotlib.text.Annotation object at 0x7f668f2a0710>
<matplotlib.text.Annotation object at 0x7f668f2a0850>
<matplotlib.text.Annotation object at 0x7f668f2a0910>
<matplotlib.text.Annotation object at 0x7f668f2a09d0>
<matplotlib.text.Annotation object at 0x7f668f2a0a90>
<matplotlib.text.Annotation object at 0x7f668f2a0b50>
>>> plt.show()
```